# Probability of co-occurence

Tags: probability, statistics

Of total $N$ people, $m$ people are good at mathematics and $c$ people are good at computer science. What is the expected number of people good at both mathematics and computer science? Or what is the probability that $r$ people are good at both mathematics and computer science. 
The formula I have derived is

$$P(r)= C(N,r)*C(N-r , m-r) * C(N-m, c-r) / ( C(N,m) * C(N,n))  $$

$N$=Total people
$m$=number of people good at math
$c$=number of people good at computer
$r$= number of people good at both

But it contains $n!$, $p!$, $c!$ etc which is difficult to compute for large values (my real problem has large values for all of these). I am looking for a neat workable formula, I am hoping it exist since it is such a basic problem.

Note: I am interested in the case where peoples are fixed and get used up. So it's basically like pushing peoples around in a given number of position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the people $1,2,3,\dots,N$. Define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if Person $i$ is good at both mathematics and computer science, and by $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then the number $Y$ of people good at both is $X_1+\cdots+X_N$, and by the linearity of expectation $E(Y)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_N)$.

Note that $E(X_i)=\Pr(X_i=1)$. By independence, this is $\frac{m}{N}\cdot \frac{c}{N}$.

Thus $E(Y)=N\cdot \frac{m}{N}\cdot\frac{c}{N}$.